# How to prompt for user input until some condition is met in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

This program keeps showing the error message and doesn't break out of the `while` statement:

```
puts "rate it"
rating = gets.chomp.to_i
while rating != 1..4
  puts "error it has to be comprised between 1 and 4"
  puts "rate it"
  rating = gets.chomp.to_i
  break if rating == 1..4
end
puts "rated"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to fix the way you check the range of `rating`: `rating == 1..4` does not check that `rating` is between 1 and 4. It checks whether `rating` *is the range object* `1..4`.

So, change `while rating != 1..4` to `while !(1..4).member?(rating)`. Also, do a similar change in the `break` statement.

While we're at it, you might as well just remove the `break` statement, since the `while` condition will break the loop when `rating` has a correct value.

#### Edit

As Stefan pointed out in the comments, there is quite a bit of duplication in the code that can easily be removed and using `between(1, 4)` as a loop exit condition is more readable.

Here's the updated code:

```
loop do
  puts "rate it"
  rating = gets.chomp.to_i
  break if rating.between?(1, 4)
  puts "error it has to be comprised between 1 and 4"
end

puts "rated"
```

Comment: Although it works, `while !(1..4).member? rating` seems quite complicated. What about `until rating.between?(1, 4)`. And you could probably avoid the duplication by wrapping the entire code into a loop.

Comment: @Stefan Great suggestion! I ended up using `break` instead of `until` to be able to also display the error message after wrong input.

Comment: You can pass `puts "rated"` as an argument to `break` if you want to keep everything inside of the loop block. Though some may feel `break puts 'rated'...` doesn't read very well.